# Huge Json Parser

Tags: java, json

I have this custom parser, made in Java, where I want to export a 3,6 GB Json into an Sql Oracle database. The import works fine with a sample Json of 8MB. But when I try parsing the whole 3,6 GB JSON some memory problems appear, namely  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

I have used -Xmx5000m  to allocate 5 GB of memory for this. My laptop has plenty of RAM.

[image: Resource usage]

[image: Error message]

As you can see I have memory left. Does this error happen because of the CPU?

UPDATE:
The Json represents the data from Free Code Camp: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/free-code-camp-christmas-special-giving-the-gift-of-data-6ecbf0313d62#.7mjj6abbg

The Data looks like this:

[
  {
    “name”: “Waypoint: Say Hello to HTML Elements”,
    “completedDate”: 1445854025698,
    “solution”: “

## Hello World

\n”
  }
]

As I've said, I have tried this parsing with an 8MB sample Json with the same data and it worked. So is the code really the problem here?

Here is some code

```
enter code here
public class MainParser {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Date time;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("output.json")); //destination to json here
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<List<Tasks>>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<List<Tasks>> details = gson.fromJson(br, collectionType);

        DBConnect connection = new DBConnect("STUDENT","student");
        connection.connect();

    for (int person=0;person<details.size();person++)
    {

        for (int task = 0; task < details.get(person).size(); task++)
        {
            connection.insert_query(person + 1,
                    task + 1,
                    details.get(person).get(task).getName(),
                     (details.get(person).get(task).getCompletedDate()/1000),
                    details.get(person).get(task).getSolution());
        }
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the insert_query method:

```
enter code here
public void insert_query(int person_id, int task_id, String taskName, double       date, String solution) throws SQLException {


           Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO FreeCodeCamp VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1,person_id);
        ps.setInt(2,task_id);
        ps.setString(3,taskName);
        ps.setDate(4,null);
        ps.setString(5,solution);
        /*stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO FreeCodeCamp VALUES("
                + person_id + ","
                + task_id + ","
                + "'" + taskName + "',"
                + "TO_TIMESTAMP(unix_ts_to_date(" + date + "),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),"
                + "'" + solution + "')");
        stmt.close();*/
        ps.execute();
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots for text information. Copy/paste the relevant information and format as code (indent 4 spaces) for things like stack traces.

Comment: attaching some code to your question would make it helpful to answer

Comment: does each json records represents a single row?

Comment: this is the JSON I am parsing https://medium.freecodecamp.com/free-code-camp-christmas-special-giving-the-gift-of-data-6ecbf0313d62#.7mjj6abbg

Comment: Try to use `streaming` approach to parse json: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: And no it does not happen because of your CPU.Post your code and the stack trace .

Comment: It happens only becuase of Huge amount of data cannot have enough memory to load on your System.
Please use any streaming concept to do this. thanxx @prometheus21

Comment: Ok, I will use this streaming approach...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing JSON (or anything, for that matter) will not take the same memory of the original file size.

Each block of JSON string that represent an object, will become an object, ADDING memory to the already loaded JSON. If you parse it using a some kind of stream, you will still add memory but to much less (you won't hold the entire 3.6GB file in memory).

Still, an object takes more memory to represent than the string. If you have an array, which might be parsed to a list, than there is overhead to that list. Multiply that overhead by the instances you have in the JSON (quite a lot, in a 3.6 GB file) and you end up with something taking much more than just 3.6GB in memory.

But if you want to parse it as a stream, and handle each record as it goes, then discard it, you can do that. In both cases for using a stream you'll need a component that parses the JSON and let you handle each parsed object. If you know the structure it just might be easier to write one yourself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful, I will modify my approach to parsing this JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an event-based / streaming JSON parser.  The idea is that instead of parsing the entire JSON file in one go and holding it in memory, the parser emits "events" at the start and end of each significant syntactic unit.  Then you write your code to handle these events, extra and assemble the information and (in your case) insert the corresponding records into your database.

Here are some places to start reading about Oracle's streaming JSON APIs:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

and here is a link to the documentation for the GSON equivalent:

- https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

See [Gson's Streaming doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

This is used when the whole model cannot be loaded into memory